# Search Partial Query Given Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to write a php function that displays people given a partial query of an ID. I currently have the code working to accept a fully query of the ID but cannot figure out a way to manipulate my code to return values for a partial string.

The Code

```
function display_person($id) {
    global $people;
    if(array_key_exists($id, $people)) {
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($people[$id]);
    } else {
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    }
}
```

The Array

```
$people = array(
'jjones' => array(
    'firstName' => 'Jim', 
    'lastName' => 'Jones', 
    'age' => 20, 
    'major' => 'Computer Science', 
    'phone' => '212-460-9393', 
    'email' => 'jjones@miamioh.edu', 
    'state' => 'OH'
),
'asmith' => array(
    'firstName' => 'April', 
    'lastName' => 'Smith', 
    'age' => 19, 
    'major' => 'Mechanical Engineering', 
    'phone' => '913-939-3929', 
    'email' => 'asmith@miamioh.edu', 
    'state' => 'WY'
),
'pstemple' => array(
    'firstName' => 'Pat', 
    'lastName' => 'Stemple', 
    'age' => 21, 'major' => 
    'Theater Performance', 
    'phone' => '917-222-2232', 
    'email' => 'pstemple@miamioh.edu', 
    'state' => 'NY'
),
'jjones1' => array(
    'firstName' => 'Janet', 
    'lastName' => 'Jones', 
    'age' => 22, 
    'major' => 'Botany', 
    'phone' => '817-332-9392', 
    'email' => 'jjones1@miamioh.edu', 
    'state' => 'CA'
),
'llerner' => array(
    'firstName' => 'Leon', 
    'lastName' => 'Lerner', 
    'age' => 18, 
    'major' => 'Biology', 
    'phone' => '315-444-3494', 
    'email' => 'llerner@miamioh.edu', 
    'state' => 'OH'
),
'mmeyer' => array(
    'firstName' => 'Margret', 
    'lastName' => 'Meyer', 
    'age' => 24, 
    'major' => 'Interactive Media Studies', 
    'phone' => '219-333-0303', 
    'email' => 'mmeyer@miamioh.edu', 
    'state' => 'OH'
),
'achaudhry' => array(
    'firstName' => 'Anik', 
    'lastName' => 'Chaudhry', 
    'age' => 19, 
    'major' => 'Management Information Systems', 
    'phone' => '914-555-5555', 
    'email' => 'achaudhry@miamioh.edu', 
    'state' => 'NY'
),
'sdogg' => array(
    'firstName' => 'Snoop', 
    'lastName' => 'Dogg', 
    'age' => 42, 
    'major' => 'Botany', 
    'phone' => '414-333-2433', 
    'email' => 'sdogg@miamioh.edu', 
    'state' => 'CA'
),
'bclinton' => array(
    'firstName' => 'Bill', 
    'lastName' => 'Clinton', 
    'age' => 25, 
    'major' => 'Political Science', 
    'phone' => '933-440-3033', 
    'email' => 'bclinton@miamioh.edu', 
    'state' => 'AK'
)
);
```

Comment: What is the ID you're trying to search with?

Comment: Do not use global, its bad.

Comment: @AmalMurali for example if I type JJONES as a query it echo return the values for JJONES. I want it to echo the values for JJONES and JJONES1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to provide only 1 output, you can slightly modify your code to:

```
function display_person($query) {
global $people;

$foundid = false;
foreach ($people as $k => $v)
    if (stripos($k, $query) !== false)
    {
        $foundid = $k;
        break;
    }

if($foundid !== false) {
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($people[$foundid]);
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
}
}
```

another approach is to find all possible variants (for this you need temporary array)

```
function display_person($query) {
global $people;

$foundid = array();
foreach ($people as $k => $v)
    if (stripos($k, $query) !== false)
    {
        $foundid[$k] = $v;
    }

if(count($foundid) > 0) {
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($foundid); // NOTE: you need to change your JS code to accept array instead of 1 person
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
}
}
```

also, I suggest you to check whether $query is long enough, usually 3+ symbols

Answer (score 2):

### Use [`similar_text()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) for your example...

#### Explanation :

Set a percentage of **80** for the similarity between the matches and those matched strings will be added in the `$sim` array. You can then `json_encode()` it *finally*.

#### The code...

```
function display_person_new($id,$people) {
    $arr = array_keys($people);
    foreach($arr as $v)
    {
        similar_text($id,$v,$percent);
        if($percent>80)
        {
            $sim[$v]=$people[$v];
        }
    }
    if(!empty($sim))
    {
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($sim,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    } else { header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'); }
}

display_person_new('jjone',$people);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
{
    "jjones": {
        "firstName": "Jim",
        "lastName": "Jones",
        "age": 20,
        "major": "Computer Science",
        "phone": "212-460-9393",
        "email": "jjones@miamioh.edu",
        "state": "OH"
    },
    "jjones1": {
        "firstName": "Janet",
        "lastName": "Jones",
        "age": 22,
        "major": "Botany",
        "phone": "817-332-9392",
        "email": "jjones1@miamioh.edu",
        "state": "CA"
    }
}
```

Comment: Might want to note that you've lost the IDs in your output

Comment: it will be really helpful if you tell me why you use $sim[$v]=$people[$v]; here ...$v returns value ie..Array ( [0] => jjones) .so are you using the value as $im[$value] ie $sim['jjones'] ?

Comment: `$v` is not an an array , it is the key.. The `$v` is one of the values from the `array_keys()`

Comment: see you have use array_keys function .so it returns the key of the array ..like Array ( [0] => key1 [1] => key2 [2] => key3 ) ..so when you use foreach it iterates the value ie,key1,key2,key3.what my question is that when you call   $sim[$v]=$people[$v]; .is $v coresponds to keys like [0],[1],[2]... ??

Comment: I am not calling anything, Just assigning the key to `$sim` array by doing `$sim[$v]` and the array corresponding to this key `$v` will be pushed to this `$sim` array when I do `$sim[$v] = $people[$v];`

Comment: so the key of $people is added to $sim[$v] so ..the array is pushedd ..right ??/

Comment: @CodeLover, You got it ;)

Answer (score 1):

First, create an array of matching keys. For example

```
$matchingIds = array_filter(array_keys($people), function($pid) use ($id) {
    // perform a case insensitive search for $id in $pid
    return stripos($pid, $id) !== false;
});
```

then, intersect this array with your `$people` keys

```
$matches = array_intersect_key($people, array_flip($matchingIds));
// array_flip allows us to flip the matching ID values into keys
// so we can intersect with the $people keys

if (count($matches)) {
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($matches);
} else {
    http_response_code(404);
    echo 'No matches found';
}
```

and finally, I would do away with the `global` variable. Using them makes testing difficult and adds a dependency on global state (this is bad). Instead, inject the `$people` array into the function when you call it

```
function display_person($id, array $people) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function display_person($id)
{
    global $people;

    foreach ($people as $key => $value)
    {
        if (strpos($key, $id) === 0)
        {
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($people[$key]) . "<br>";
        } else
        {
            header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
        }
    }
}
```